# Does God feel and appreciate the resiliency of our suffering?

Tags: will-of-god, suffering

First of all, this is not meant to be a personal posting. I just want to know how God feels about the intense suffering of others who really love and care for Him in the midst of their utmost suffering. So this witness to suffering and this posting. I want to know what the Bible says on this topic.

If a person is psychologically ill with 6 different illnesses and has been suffering for over 22 years, went through 3 MRIs, 2 CAT scan, 1 endoscopy, 2 CT scan, 3 ECG, 1 EEG, myriad blood, urine, and stool sample testing, 11 times to emergency section of all the hospitals in the city, have personal problems, housing problems, financial problems, other burning problems, tested all the meds in the pharmaceutical market and current one suits him best but made him intellectually inferior, created concentration problem and lethargic behavior, when he uses subway or bus or any transit system he has intense headache because of his illnesses and he is still upbeat and resilient about it, does God appreciate his honesty and resiliency?

Does God know how much he cares about Him and how much he loves Him that he accepted all these suffering in his life looking at the cross-section of two lumber bars?

He eats healthy and works out every day. Go to the doctor's office every week. Go to therapy sessions. He is trying hard to harder to hardest after every single new day to get better. He doesn't care if God will return his health, wealth, life and job back like Job in the Bible, but this he knows he loves God very much. He loves Him so much that still he laughs and smiles amid his intense pain, suffering, and torment. He doesn't feel miserable or asks for pity at all.

Instead, I want to know **where in the Bible it has been stated that God feels the suffering of that man like that distressed man does and appreciates his strong resiliency against all the vice in his life**?

“We are hard-pressed on every side, but not crushed; perplexed, but not in despair; persecuted, but not abandoned; struck down, but not destroyed” (2 Corinthians 4:8–9)

St. Paul It is in our suffering that we find strength.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast I am thinking of more in general terms. Does God appreciate that we are offering up all our suffering to Him and trying our best to alleviate a fraction of an infinitesimally small fraction of Christ's suffering? Does He experience our suffering as we do with our flesh and blood? Does He applaud and tear up in gladness when He sees our resiliency no matter how big or small the challenge is that we face every day? Does He appreciate our every sweat, every perspiration and every tiny cross that He has given into our lives with much care (but it seems so impossible to us)?

Comment: OK, there are a number of ways to answer this, I offered one based in scripture and my faith tradition.  Best wishes and blessings to you

Comment: @KorvinStarmast Thank you sir for your thoughtful and thought-provoking insight. God the Son paid the heaviest price for our inequities. So I personally think that if Christ carried the heaviest laden cross that is not His then why can't I suffer that is justifiably mine? I started the echo inside of me a long time ago and am trying my best within my utmost effort to lift up the heavy burden of mine that is burdening Him more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### To experience suffering is to configure one's self to / with Christ

> ... already in the act of Baptism, which brings about a configuration with Christ, and then through his Sacrifice...the Church is continually being built up spiritually as the Body of Christ. In this Body, Christ wishes to be united with every individual, and in a special way he is united with those who suffer.  (Salvifici Doloris, 24)

While this answer begins with what I was taught by a Catholic deacon some years ago, on a more biblical basis you will find in Collosians a complete embracing of suffering

1 Collosians 23, 24,

> Now **I rejoice in my sufferings for your sake**, and in my flesh I am filling up what is lacking in the afflictions of Christ on behalf of his body, which is the church,

One of the themes that the Catholics teach is that our suffering configures us with Christ, who suffered on the Cross for all of our sins.  There is an extended meditation [here in Salvifici Doloris](http://www.vatican.va/roman_curia/pontifical_councils/hlthwork/documents/hf_jp-ii_apl_11021984_salvifici-doloris_en.html) covering *the Christian meaning of human suffering*.  Pope St. John Paul II observes that

> ... we recall the truth expressed in the Encyclical *Redemptor
>   Hominis*: in Christ "every man becomes the way for the Church." It can
>   be said that man in a special fashion becomes the way for the Church
>   when suffering enters his life. This happens, as we know, at different
>   moments in life, it takes place in different ways, it assumes
>   different dimensions; nevertheless, in whatever form, suffering seems
>   to be, and is, almost inseparable from man's earthly existence.

That's one take of many on the topic of suffering.

#### You ask "does God feel and appreciate the resiliency of our suffering?"

I answer: Yes.   God is with us *always*.

John 14: 16- 17 (NAB)

> And I will ask the Father, and he will give you another Advocate 8 to
>   be with you always, the Spirit of truth, which the world cannot
>   accept, because it neither sees nor knows it. But you know it, because
>   it remains with you, and will be in you.

Under the basis of the trinitarian Godhead, the Son felt mankind's suffering on the Cross. Because the Father and the Son are one - 
John 10: 30

> The Father and I are one."

... God knows what Jesus feels, what Jesus felt.

#### What about *appreciating* the resiliency of our suffering?

The Holy Spirit is sent to us from God to be with us always(see above). Beyond God knowing of our suffering (God knows all) and appreciating our suffering (through the person of Christ and the Cross) the appreciation by God of our suffering is a Christian belief that goes back to the early church; the original Saints were martyrs for Christ.

- This Christian belief, that the saints of the early church, most of whom were Martyrs for the Church (just as Christ was martyred for all of us) and thereby earned the reward of Heaven shows but one example of God appreciating the suffering of individuals.  (There have been entire books written on this topic).

#### From a contemporary Christian point of view ...

... the answer remains **Yes**.  There is a well known poem: *Footprints in the Sand* by Margaret Fishback Powers

> “One night I dreamed a dream. As I was walking along the beach with my
>   Lord. Across the dark sky flashed scenes from my life. For each scene,
>   I noticed two sets of footprints in the sand, One belonging to me and
>   one to my Lord.
>
> After the last scene of my life flashed before me, I looked back at
>   the footprints in the sand. I noticed that at many times along the
>   path of my life, especially at the very lowest and saddest times,
>   there was only one set of footprints.
>
> This really troubled me, so I asked the Lord about it. “Lord, you said
>   once I decided to follow you, You’d walk with me all the way. But I
>   noticed that during the saddest and most troublesome times of my life,
>   there was only one set of footprints. I don’t understand why, when I
>   needed You the most, You would leave me.”
>
> He whispered, “My precious child, I love you and will never leave you
>   Never, ever, during your trials and testings. When you saw only one
>   set of footprints, It was then that I carried you.”

The message here is clear: the personal connection with Christ, who cares for us regardless of our condition, and is another perspective on how God will be with us always.   He doesn't just appreciate our suffering, He's there to help when we suffer.  That message is pretty clear across multiple Christian denominations.

---

Another excerpt from [that extended meditation on suffering](http://www.vatican.va/roman_curia/pontifical_councils/hlthwork/documents/hf_jp-ii_apl_11021984_salvifici-doloris_en.html)

> The Redeemer suffered in place of man and for man. Every man has his
>   own share in the Redemption. *Each one is also called to share in that
>   suffering through which the Redemption was accomplished. He is called
>   to share in that suffering through which all human suffering has also
>   been redeemed. In bringing about the Redemption through suffering,
>   Christ has also raised human suffering to the level of the Redemption.*
>   Thus each man, in his suffering, can also become a sharer in the
>   redemptive suffering of Christ.

Comment: I also believe suffering is an indivisible part of human life.  Without suffering there is no salvation. There is no alternate route or easy way out. I strongly believe from the richest (billionaire or millionaire) person to Kings and Queens to poor and vulnerable people, everybody carries the cross of Christ. The intensity level is just different. Through suffering, a human person becomes closer to God. By witnessing suffering a family, a person, a society or a nation can transform. And that's the bigger picture. Sometimes we feel overwhelmed but with Godeverything'spossible